# Loading a Child (Navigation Property) Entity not working

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am having a very tough time with this one.  I have a Navigation property called Attachment that is part of an entity called ContentChannel.  ContentChannel is a many to one relationship with KioskType.

In my domain service extension class, I have the following query:

```
public IQueryable<ContentChannel> GetContentChannelFromKioskType( long kioskTypeID )
{
    var returnSet = (from cc in ObjectContext.ContentChannels.Include( "Attachment" )
                   join pcc in ObjectContext.PublishedContentChannels on cc.ContentChannelID equals pcc.ContentChannelID
                        where pcc.KioskTypeID == kioskTypeID
                        select cc);
    return returnSet;
}
```

And this works just fine for returning the list of ContentChannels.  But the Attachment in each ContentChannel is null.

I have tried `[Include]` on the attachment property in my ContentChannel metadata class, in conjuction with `ContentChannels.Include("Attachment")` in the above query- no luck, Attachment is always null.

I dug more and then found something to explicitly load my child item:

```
ObjectContext.LoadProperty( returnSet, "Attachment" );
```

But this generates the following error:

Cannot explicitly load property for entities that are detached.  Objects loaded using the NoTracking merge option are always detached.

Is it because I'm doing a join that things are wonky and the Include doesnt work?  What do I need to do?  These attachments need to get loaded when I get a ContentChannel!

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including the `join` in your query, you've changed the shape of the query, after the `Include`. So the `Include is discarded`. [But you don't need the `join`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/):

```
public IQueryable<ContentChannel> GetContentChannelFromKioskType( long kioskTypeID )
{
    var returnSet = (from cc in ObjectContext.ContentChannels.Include( "Attachment" )
                     where cc.PublishedContentChannels.Any(pcc => pcc.KioskTypeID == kioskTypeID)
                     select cc);
    return returnSet;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt compile.  cc does have ContentChannel in it, it has PublishedContentChannels- and I cant access KioskTypeID in PCC.  Nice article though!

Comment: Well, I had to guess at the association/navigation name and multiplicity. I'll update the answer with the info you've added

Comment: This worked:  (from cc in ObjectContext.ContentChannels.Include( "Attachment" )
        from pcc in cc.PublishedContentChannels.Where(e => e.KioskTypeID == kioskTypeID)
        select cc) But I still needed the Where statement and a from; you used a where then any.  Is this correct as well?

Comment: Correct? Maybe. It's different. Your version returns 1 row per PCC (so if a CC has 2 PCCs, you get 2 CC rows with the same CC). Mine returns 1 per CC. Pick whichever is right for you.